# Visual Studio on Windows - add libs to Linux project

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

I'm using `Visual Studio` on a computer with `Windows OS`. I've created a `Linux` project and set up a connection to my Linux computer. I can correctly create, compile and debug simple C++ code.

I have a problem when I have to use libs, that are not easily downloadable on `Linux`.
I need to use `GameNetworkingSockets`, so I've downloaded it using `vcpkg`, but `Visual Studio` cannot find these libs, because they are not in the `Linux` dir with libs.
I've tried to change project settings and change `Additional Library Directories`, but still `VS` cannot find them.

Question: How can I correctly handle additional libs, when compiling a `Linux` project in `Visual Studio` from a computer with `Windows`?

P.S.: I'm not a good `Linux` user, so be patient, please :)